# Having trouble being able to use response JSON data after a fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am using react and my objective is to get a specific URL into an href by calling a function that gets the URL from the Spotify API. the function looks like this:

```
<a href={Spotify.getPreviewUrl(this.props.track.ID).then(results => {
                        console.log(results);
                        return results;
                    })}>Track Preview</a>
```

This then calls a function that gets the URL from the Spotify API:

```
 getPreviewUrl(trackId) {
            return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${trackId}`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${usersAccessToken}`
                }
            }).then(response =>
                response.json()).then(jsonResponse => {
                console.log(jsonResponse);
                return jsonResponse.preview_url;
                });
            }
```

Now back in my initial call:

```
<a href={Spotify.getPreviewUrl(this.props.track.ID).then(results => {
                        console.log(results);
                        return results;
                    })}>Track Preview</a>
```

The `console.log()` value is exactly the URL I want but it is not becoming the href URL address like I want it too even though I'm returning that value. Does anyone know how I can get that value to be the actual href URL?

Comment: you're trying to set an attribute asynchronously - the reason the console.log is correct is because it is correct once `getPreviewUrl` resolves - but you can't set attributes like that

Comment: You want `<a href={this.state.previewURL}>` paired with `componentDidMount() { Spotify.[.....].then(respone => this.setState({ previewURL: response.preview_url })` so that react can simply do what it's supposed to: update your UI based on state/props updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use  a state variable to store the result of fetch and assign it to the href,

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={link:null};
}

componentDidMount(){
   Spotify.getPreviewUrl(this.props.track.ID).then(results => {
      this.setState({link:results});
    })
}
....
render(){
  return ...
        <a href={this.state.link}>Track Preview</a>
}
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason Im getting an infinite loop that accors when I update state and I cant figure it out?

Comment: Did you update your state in side render()? that is against the rules of  react and will cause rerendering endlessly

Answer (score 0):

Try using `componentDidMount` in conjunction with React `state`.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/9zr4znl8mo (**replace `token` with a valid Spotify token!**)

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import ShowError from "./ShowError";
import ShowTrack from "./ShowTrack";

export default class Spotify extends Component {
  state = {
    artist: "",
    err: "",
    image: "",
    isLoading: true,
    link: "",
    token: "FAKE_TOKEN",
    trackName: "",
    trackId: "2Ll0eOXFmIeBlcybOSaQJm"
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { token, trackId } = this.state;

    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${trackId}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(({ artists, name, preview_url, album: { images } }) =>
        this.setState({
          artist: artists && artists.length > 0 ? artists[0].name : null,
          link: preview_url,
          image: images && images.length > 0 ? images[0].url : null,
          isLoading: false,
          trackName: name
        })
      )
      .catch(err => this.setState({ err: err.toString(), isLoading: false }));
  };

  render = () =>
    this.state.err 
      ? <ShowError err={this.state.err} />
      : this.state.isLoading
        ? <Spinner />
        : <ShowTrack {...this.state} />
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
      // return a Promise from within .then() as enter code here
       const getResult = (result) => result;
       const Promise = require('bluebird');
       let promisifiedResult = Promise.promisify(getResult);


       getPreviewUrl(trackId) {
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${trackId}`, 
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${usersAccessToken}`
            }
        }).then(response =>
            response.json()).then(jsonResponse => {
               return promisifiedResult (jsonResponse.preview_url);
            });
        }
```